# Why can't I set class constructor parameter to a default value?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default

```
template<class KeyType, class ValueType, class Hash = std::hash<KeyType> >
class HashMap {
 public:
    Hash hasher;

    HashMap(Hash override_ = hasher) {
        hasher = override_;
    }
};
```

Here is my code. What I expect to happen is that I keep the default value for `hasher` if none was supplied by the constructor, or change it to new otherwise. What I get is this: `invalid use of non-static data member 'hasher'`. I've already figured I can replace `hasher` with `Hash()` as a default value; but what if I needed not a default `Hash` object but something more complicated? And why did my first attempt not compile?

Comment: Default arguments for the constructor are resolved before the object construction begins, so `hasher` would not exist at that time

Comment: A good solution would be 2 constructors, the other being `HashMap(){}`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use as default value for constructor parameter a member of a the class while the object as not been created yet. That cannot work unless the member is static. In order to do what you want, you can define 2 constructors, this way:

```
#include <map>
template<class KeyType, class ValueType, class Hash = std::hash<KeyType> >
class HashMap {
public:
    Hash hasher;

    HashMap(Hash override_) {
        hasher = override_;
    }
    HashMap() {
    }
};
```

Comment: What I don't understand is _why_ I can't use it this way. I've already circumvented this problem by using `Hash()` as a default value, so my question is more about "Why?" than about "How?".

Comment: @Akiiino `hasher` is not created yet at that point, how are going to use it?

Comment: @Slava but what if it was `static` --- when I create first `HashMap`, it is not created yet as well, or is it?

Comment: @Akiiino: if the member is static, it is created at program initialization and does not need an instance; a non static member is created at object instanciation.

Comment: @shrike Are you sure that's the case? Since my class has template parameters, and different instances with different template parameters do not share their `static`s, it would seem unlikely that a `static` variable would be generated for every possible combination of parameters.

Comment: @Akiiino: not for every possible combination, only for the combinations that are used in a template instantiation

Answer (score 0):

It is forbidden as per standards . This is detailed in section 8.3.6 of the C++03 standard. It basically amounts to any expression that doesn't depend on anything in local scope, so any expression which depends on local variables, parameters to a function, or on "this" are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is this:

```
template<class KeyType, class ValueType, class Hash = std::hash<KeyType> >
class HashMap {
 public:
    Hash hasher;

    HashMap(Hash override_ = {}) : hasher{std::move(override_)} {}
};
```

If none provided, the default constructor is called.

Personally, I think the best option would be to add a default constructor:

```
template<class KeyType, class ValueType, class Hash = std::hash<KeyType> >
class HashMap {
 public:
    Hash hasher;

    HashMap() = default;
    HashMap(Hash override_) : hasher{std::move(override_)} {}
};
```